# AlertDialog is not dismissed automatically if getButton and setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I used to use `AlertDialog.Builder` to create an alert dialog and set the onClickListener of the buttons of the dialog; but recently when I tried

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder
.setTitle("xxx")
.setPositiveButton("xxx", null)
.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dlg, null));

alertDlg=builder.create();
alertDlg.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         //do sth.
    }
}
```

, the alertDlg **won't** be dismissed automatically, and i have to add `alertDlg.dismiss();` manually after `//do sth.` in  method `onClick`.

I know `builder.setPositiveButton("xxx", new OnClickListener(){})` is a good way, but I just want to know what's wrong with the code above, is that a bug on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get button in the `AlertDialog.Builder` class before Setting it using the `setPositiveButton` or `setNegativeButton` or even `setNeutralButton`. 
If the button does not exist it will return null.

According to the Android documentation:

**getButton()**

`Gets one of the buttons used in the dialog.`

`If a button does not exist in the dialog, null will be returned.`

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton(int)

Comment: I used `builder.setPositiveButton("xxx", null)` to set the positive button, as I've edited my code in the post. I just want to set the onClickListener a bit later

Comment: if my code returns **null** , there will be a NullPointerException

Comment: the reason i wanna set the listener later is because i want to deal with the widget in R.layout.alert_dlg in the listener, while the layout is not setup yet before builder.create(), if `build.show()` directly, how can i deal with the widget?

Answer (score 0):

Because a View onClickListener is different to DialogInterface's onClickListener in the way that it remove's the parent view from view.

Comment: You're right, it's different. But here it's not the case. Otherwise he could've never override the onClick() method properly. A compilation error would've certainly occured.